How to ignore single quotes in the validator.js isAlphanumeric function
I am trying to validate a string using express validator, specifically with the function isAlphanumeric, but I would like to add space, dash, and single quote as characters to accept.
Here is my code:
body("title")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .escape()
    .withMessage("Le champ titre est obligatoire.")
    .isAlphanumeric("fr-FR", { ignore: " -'" })
    .withMessage("Le champ titre contient des caractères non autorisés."),

With this code, I can type in strings with dashes and spaces in the HTML form without them being rejected, but if I add a single quote, I get a validation error with the last "withMessage" error. The string does not pass the isAlphanumeric test.
I thought of a character escaping problem inside of the "ignore" string, so I have tried the following:

" -\'"
" -'\''" (as seen here on another question) - quote backslash quote quote
/ -'/ (using RegExp)
/[ -']/ (and every combination with \ and [], I think)

I cannot find the proper way to include the single quote in the "ignore" option of the isAlphanumeric validator, and I feel like I am trying anything randomly until I find the right way to do it, which is not really satisfying. As everything works fine with other characters, I still think of a character escaping problem but I cannot figure out which one.
I am sure that ignoring single quotes has already been done, but I could not find the answer on Google or Stack Overflow, so I guess it was time I signed up on this site to ask this question by myself.
I would like a "regexp-free" solution if it exists, as it must be doable with the string version (I still need to improve my regexp skill).
Edit
I wish to precise that I tried adding a middleware before the 'body("title")' validator:
(req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body.title);
    next();
},

The string that I type in the form is correctly stored in the req.body.title variable ("Le Mal n'existe pas"), as I could check with console.log, so I do not have any problem with the initial string before validation.
Found it! (the solution)
I removed .escape(), as it changes the ' into &#x27;
It was almost obvious, but it took me a day to think of this escape function.
The .escape() function must be used after the isAlphanumeric validator.

you can create new regex with: 
const rgx = new RegExp("-|\'") 
the "|" in the middle means "or" 
also if it doesnt work you can try two backslashes like "-\\'" or "-|\\'"

Thank you for your answer, but it does not change the fact that the single quote ' does not pass the validation test.
I think the or '|' symbol does not change anything, as I already had several characters in the ignore string " -" (space and dash), and I can add others such as '!' and it works.
The ignore string is already an "OR" by itself.
I tried any combination of \ backslashes. If the " -'" ignore string does work for you and everybody else, then the problem must be elsewhere in my code.
